# Complexity of membership testing for finite-regular languages

Tags: time-complexity, regular-languages, finite-automata

A language $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is *finite-regular* if there exists $C$ such that for all $n$, $L \cap \Sigma^n$ is accepted by some DFA with at most $C$ final states.

Given a finite-regular language $A_L$, am I guaranteed that there exists a polynomial-time algorithm $A_L$ that recognizes $L$?  In other words, I want an algorithm such that on input $x$ it returns true or false according to whether $x \in L$ or not, and the running time is polynomial in the length of $x$.  Is this guaranteed?

Note that the number of states of the complete DFA accepting such $L$ may be $O(|\Sigma|^n)$ so any trivial algorithm actually constructing the full DFA would not be polynomial time. However the number of accepting final states is $O(1)$, which leads me to believe there is some shortcut available here.

Thanks to Yuval Filmus for [formalizing](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79865/simulating-dfa-operations-on-non-regular-languages-with-finite-final-state-set/79866#79866) this language class, and explaining its closure properties.

Comment: Let me know whether my edit accurately captures your intent.  Am I right that you allow the algorithm to depend on the language $L$?  Or do you want a single universal algorithm that on input $x$ and a specification of the language $L$, tests whether $x \in L$?  If the latter, how are you planning to specify $L$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finite-regular languages need not even be decidable. Indeed, if $L$ is *any* language such that $|L \cap \Sigma^n| \leq C$ for some $C$ independent of $n$, then $L$ is finite-regular (you can show this by considering the case $C=1$). In particular, the language $\{ 1^n : \text{ the $n$th Turing machine halts on the empty input} \}$ is finite-regular but not decidable.

Comment: "if $L$ is *any* language such that $|L \cap \Sigma^n| \leq C$ for some $C$ independent of $n$" - I must be missing something. Wouldn't such a language be finite?

Comment: @user2357112 No. Consider any language $L\subseteq\{a\}^*$. We have $|L\cap\{a\}^n|\leq 1$ but $L$ can be infinite.

Comment: Oh - I was thinking of strings up to length $n$, not exactly length $n$.